# How to pass and return data in the next middleware in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to pass data from one middleware to another. The data is then returned to the client in the next middleware. I, however, am unable to catch it in the `send.call`.

How can I catch the data and send it?

Thank you all in advance.

```
const myPreMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    req.myData = myData;

    next();
};

const myPostMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    let send = res.send;

    res.send = async function (body) {
        send.call(this, req.myData); // The data i NOT accessible here
    };

    console.log("req.myData : " + JSON.stringify(req.myData)); // The data is accessible here

    next();
};

app.use(myPreMiddleware);
app.use(myPostMiddleware);
```

Comment: What's in `req` inside a wrapped `send` function?

Comment: That's the data from a previous middleware.

Comment: You wrote that `req.myData` is inaccessible. Did you look at `req` itself there?

Answer (score 0):

Try pass the variable that you want to pass to the `next()` callback

here some example that will hopefully help

```
function notFound(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404);
  const error = new Error(`Not Found - ${req.originalUrl}`);
  next(error);
}

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode !== 200 ? res.statusCode : 500;
  res.status(statusCode);
  res.json({
    message: err.message
  });
}


app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);
```